# Python. Best way to "zip" char and list

Tags: python, list, char, zip

I want to "zip" char and list in Python:

An example:

```py
char = '<'
list = [3, 23, 67]

"zip"(char, list) 
 >>> [('<', 3), ('<', 23), ('<', 67)]
```

How I'm using **itertools.repeat()**:

```py
itertools.izip(itertools.repeat(char, len(list)), list)
>>>[('<', 3), ('<', 23), ('<', 67)]
```

It works, but it so interesting to find more pythonic solution.

Comment: It's already pythonic, don't worry. What is *pythonic* again?

Comment: You can omit second argument for repeat

Comment: `itertools.izip_longest` can be useful here, but the LC version posted by others is much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need itertools here.

Using list comprehension:

```
>>> char = '<'
>>> lst = [3, 23, 67]
>>> [(char, n) for n in lst]
[('<', 3), ('<', 23), ('<', 67)]
```

BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name. It shadows builtin function [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).

Comment: Thank you for example of using.

Answer (score 4):

```
[(char, i) for i in list]
```

Naming your list as "list" is probably not a good idea btw., as this shadows the constructor for the internal list type.

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes, I know it, and use name 'list' here for best ilustrating of example.

Answer (score 1):

If `char` is only ever going to be reused for all pairings, just use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [(char, i) for i in lst]
[('<', 3), ('<', 23), ('<', 67)]
```

If `char` is a *string* of characters, and you wanted to cycle through them when pairing (like `zip()` would for the shortest length sequence), use [`itertools.cycle()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> chars = 'fizz'
>>> lst = range(6)
>>> zip(chars, lst)
[('f', 0), ('i', 1), ('z', 2), ('z', 3)]
>>> zip(cycle(chars), lst)
[('f', 0), ('i', 1), ('z', 2), ('z', 3), ('f', 4), ('i', 5)]
```

Note how the characters of the string `'fizz'` are reused to pair up with the numbers `4` and `5`; they'll continue to be cycled to match any length list (which must be finite).

Answer (score 1):

If you want something equivalent to your use of itertools - using lazy generation for iteration - then you can use generator expressions.  The syntax is pretty much equivalent to list comprehensions except you enclose the expression with paranthesis.

```
>>> c = '<'
>>> l = [3, 23, 67]
>>> my_gen = ((c, item) for item in l)
>>> for item in my_gen:
...     print item
...
('<', 3)
('<', 23)
('<', 67)
```

For more info, here's the PEP that explains it: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use zip, here is how :

```
l  = [3, 23, 67]
zip('<' * len(l), l)

[('<', 3), ('<', 23), ('<', 67)]
```

In further details, `itertools.repeat(char, len(list))` is quite similar in result to `'<' * 3`. Also, both work with zip (you could write `zip(itertools.repeat(char, len(list)), l))`, too).